# Delete associated records when model is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am running ActiveRecord 3.2.6. Given I have these model definitions:

### My Invoice model

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :autosave => true, :dependent => :delete_all
  attr_accessible :recipient_email

  # This is just a simple wrapper with allows me to build multiple
  # items at once and to specify them as a Hash instead of Item.new.
  def items=(ary)
    super ary.map{|item| item.is_a?(Hash) ? items.build(item) : item}
  end
end
```

### My Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice

  attr_accessible :amount, :description, :invoice_id, :value
end
```

My goal is to save the invoice items directly in the model. This works without problems, when the Invoice is freshly created. One call to `Invoice#save!` and everything is saved.

```
> i = Invoice.new(:recipient_email => "foobar@example.org")
> i.items = [{amount: 10, description: "Bottles of Milk", value: 0.40},
  {amount: 1, description: "Shipping fee to Antarctica", value: 217.38}]
> i.save!
  SQL (23.5ms)  INSERT INTO "invoices" [...]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "items" [...]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "items" [...]
 => true
```

However, when I try to update the items in an `Invoice` that already exists, it deletes the old items before I save the new items.

```
# Load invoice ID 1, with two items: ID 1 and ID 2.
> i = Invoice.find(1)

# It deletes the old items here
> i.items = [{amount: 10, description: "Less buggy objective relational mappers", value: 1337.00}]
  SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM items WHERE id IN (1, 2)

# But it should delete the new items here, before inserting the new items,
# wrapping everything in a transaction.
> i.save!
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" [...]
   (192.6ms)  commit transaction
```

How can I tell ActiveRecord to delete the old items only when `Invoice#save!` is called? Or is this a bug in ActiveRecord?

### EDIT: My question - clarified

I do not want the `DELETE` queries to run when the items are assigned (`i.items = ...`), but when the invoice containing the items is saved (`invoice.save!`). It should mark the old items for deletions and the new items for insertation and then execute the query on `invoice.save!`. Is this possible with ActiveRecord?

### EDIT 2: Further clarification

As some do not get the question right, some further clarifications. I must admit, this is pretty complex. So here is the difference between what actually happens and what I want to happen.

#### What I want

This *does not* happen. I *want* it to happen. This is completely fictitious. Compare it to the listing above to see the difference.

```
# (1) Load invoice ID 1, with two items: ID 1 and ID 2.
> i = Invoice.find(1)

# (2) Assign new items, delete the old ones. New stuff exists in memory, not in database
> i.items = [{amount: 10, description: "Less buggy objective relational mappers", value: 1337.00}]

# (3) Save everything to database. Run queries.
> i.save!
   (0.0ms) begin transactions
  SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM items WHERE id IN (1, 2)
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" [...]
   (192.6ms)  commit transaction
```

#### What actually hapens

The `DELETE` query runs on at point `(2)`. But it should run at point `(3)`. (Compare to above listing).

Comment: I can totally sympathize with this.  Coming from hibernate, I expected things to work this way.  Some kind of association attribute which signals "on parent.save, synchronize db state of children with parent.children".  However, this is pretty complex to support: it would require very careful tracking of modifications to and through the association to know what should be done to the children on save.

Answer (score 0):

It will delete the old items because you configured association as autosave

```
has_many :items, :autosave => true, :dependent => :delete_all
```

Remove autosave and try again, it will work.

Comment: No, that has no effect. Did you try it yourself? By the way: I *want* it to delete the items. But not when the items are associated (`invoice.items = ...`), but when the invoice is saved (`invoice.save!`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want append action in assignment, I believe this should work:

```
  def items=(ary)
    super(ary.map{|item| item.is_a?(Hash) ? items.build(item) : item} + self.items)
  end
```

Comment: I am afraid you did not understand my question. I want the old items to be deleted. But I want them to be deleted when `save!` is called, not when `items = ...` is called. Give me a second to edit my question and further clarify that...

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your association with the `autosave: true` option and use [mark_for_destruction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-mark_for_destruction) to specified each item you want to destroy on `save`.

With your second edit in mind, you could do something like this:

```
# (1) Load invoice ID 1, with two items: ID 1 and ID 2.
> i = Invoice.find(1)

# (2) Mark the old items to be destroyed on save. They are still in memory and in the database for now.
> i.items.each(&:mark_for_destruction)

# (3) Assign new items. New stuff exists in memory, not in database.
> i.items.build([{amount: 10, description: "Less buggy objective relational mappers", value: 1337.00}])

# (4) Delete the items which has been mark for destruction. Save everything to database. Run queries.
> i.save!
   (0.0ms) begin transactions
  SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM items WHERE id IN (1, 2)
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "items" [...]
   (192.6ms)  commit transaction
```